# jQuery: Pause button to pause all other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, resume

I'm making a little game and I have a button to pause the game. How can I "pause" the game from doing any actions, but when clicking "resume" just to resume all actions as if nothing happened?

Let's say I have some complex coding, so I can't just implement a small thing in one function: it really needs to cover all "busy" things.

Thank you for your time!

Pause button:

```
function pauseGameBtn() {
    $("#pause").click(function() {
        if (pauseBtnClicked == true) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: We need to see your code to be of any effective help, but a flag as you have in your example is one way, you may also need to clear any timers you have running.

Comment: just use one div as a layer and when you press pause button then show that layer on the top of screen and set on flag that will detect that you pressed the pause button or not

Comment: The flag is a good idea. Without seeing the kinds of tasks you will be executing, it is difficult to suggest a best way. In any case, something like a "pause" for a constantly running game is something that definitely needs to be "baked in" from the outset. Every action, event, task, etc will be subject to the "pause" condition. Some tasks you might want to keep running, eg., if any characters have movement animations or something. Things like play clocks, accruals of energy or the like, you may not have to stop the timers, but use the flag to prevents variables from incrementing.

Comment: The idea of having a flag is indeed really good. I'll have to think about how  I'll be implementing that, but I guess it'll work out eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical game loop goes through a single point of code. Your timer would call that regularly and be the single place you need to check for a paused state.

This is greatly simplified, but the basic idea is:

```
var paused = false;
// endless game loop
setInterval(function(){
    if (!paused){
       RunGameLoop();  // process input => calculate => render etc
    }
}, 50);

$("#pause").click(function() {
     paused = true;
});

$("#resume").click(function() {
     paused = false;
});
```

Comment: This might be really useful. Thanks, TBA!

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo:

```
var  itv = null; // The interval

(function gameUIlogic{}(
   // Main Menu stuff
   // and other stuff independent from framerate interval
)());

function gameLogic() {
    // Game logic here
    itv = window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function pause() {
    return itv ? (window.cancelAnimationFrame(itv ), itv=null) : gameLogic();
}
```

Let's say you have a Play and Pause button, simply trigger the `pause()` function on both.